# Modify Wikitext in Mediawiki, like preSaveTransform

Tags: mediawiki

How to write an extension that will directly modify the wiki text, for mediawiki 1.16?
The free webhost only has an old version of php and so i can't install a newer version of mediawiki.

The preSaveTransform can change the signature (~~~~) into some other wikitext.

When I write a parser extension, so far, I only know to make "{{#example: hello | hi}}" to **display** as "param1 is hello and param2" but can't change the wikitext directly to that.

I saw that $wikiPage->doEditContent( $new_content, $edit_summary, $flags ); seems can do this, but unfortunately it is in version 1.20 +

update:
found
" $article->doEdit( $new_text, $edit_summary, $flags ); "
in https://git.wikimedia.org/blob/mediawiki%2Fextensions%2FReplaceText/62ec35b6c0d16419e9893c3a78b4d04076024ea2/ReplaceTextJob.php

update:
way to find the article title when writing a parser (or tag) extension:
$article = new Article($parser->getTitle(), 0 );
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgTitle

Comment: You ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the {{subst:}} magic word in MediaWiki.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Substitution

Instead of evaluating and displaying wikitext, it causes evaluated wikitext to be directly substituted into the article.

I don't know if this will solve your problem: you seem to want your own parser function to do the substitution, rather than relying on something external like subst. But at the very least, you can look at the implementation of subst in the wiki source code to figure out how it does what it does.